# Compile both 32 and 64 bit from the same projects?

Tags: c#

I am using Pcapdot.Net DLLs, both 32 and 64 bit. 
Is it possible to create one project with 32 and 64 DLLs so that after compiling it will create 2 different EXE files for 32 and for 64 bit?

Comment: ... Just create another solution configuration from the Configuration Manager which targets x64, then build... Or am I not understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie More tricky than that when conditionally including references to libraries of differing bitiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, *probabbly* (it's not very clear) is that you're linking some DLL in your project and would like to pick right DLL (32 or 64 bit) for relative build of your project.

The solution could be simply referebce in your project a DLL with common name:

say `Pcapdot.Net DLL`, for both platforms.

And in post build event of your project, based on the current configuration of the build, copy  platform specific `Pcapdot.Net DLL` into the folder where the project loads references.

So when your app loads it will load always "correct" version of the `Pcapdot.Net DLL`.

To be more clear:

Say you reference in your project a `Pcapdot.Net DLL` from

> "Debug\External"

In your project tree you have

> "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\Dlls\x86\Pcapdot.Net DLL"

and

> "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\Dlls\x64\Pcapdot.Net DLL"

Say you setuped your project fro 64 bit compilation. In post build event, you check this and
go to copy

> "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\Dlls\x64\Pcapdot.Net DLL"

into the

> "Debug\External"

.

Hope this helps.